# Error while trying to deploy my application on AWS via ElasticBean

Tags: django, postgresql

My applications work perfectly well on local server where I have configured PostgreSQL and I use PostgreSQL on remote too.

Several of my application use a Foreign Key relations to User Model,and I have used settings.`AUTH_USER_MODEL` as suggested in several other answers. But it does not solve the problem.

I have tried deleting migrations and dropping public schema on Database instant and redeploying, still no success.

Here is the log

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/python/run/venv/bin/django-admin.py", line 5, in <module>
  management.execute_from_command_line()
  File "/opt/python/run/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 338, in execute_from_command_line
  utility.execute()
  File "/opt/python/run/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 330, in execute
  self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "/opt/python/run/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 390, in run_from_argv
  self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
  File "/opt/python/run/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 441, in execute
  output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "/opt/python/run/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/syncdb.py", line 25, in handle
  call_command("migrate", **options)
  File "/opt/python/run/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 120, in call_command
  return command.execute(*args, **defaults)
  File "/opt/python/run/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 441, in execute
  output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "/opt/python/run/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/migrate.py", line 179, in handle
  created_models = self.sync_apps(connection, executor.loader.unmigrated_apps)
  File "/opt/python/run/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/migrate.py", line 317, in sync_apps
  cursor.execute(statement)
  File "/opt/python/run/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 64, in execute
  return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "/opt/python/run/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 97, in __exit__
  six.reraise(dj_exc_type, dj_exc_value, traceback)
  File "/opt/python/run/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 62, in execute
  return self.cursor.execute(sql)
  django.db.utils.ProgrammingError: relation "auth_user" does not exist
```

Is running syndb mandated in 1.8, since its being deprecated?

I am using django 1.8 with django-social-auth.

Thank you!

Comment: Check whether your database contains table `auth_user`(remember that PostgreSQL is **case sensitive**) the name in your code and the name of the table in database

Comment: it must not.
Evidently, for some reason migrations was not migrating 'auth' by default..
I ran a custom 'django-admin.py migrate auth' and it worked.

thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem by individually running 
 `django-admin.py migrate auth`

Evidently simply running `django-admin.py migrate` does not migrate the "auth" app by default. Any ideas why this should be happening?